# Can't get bitmap from drawable (Robolectric)

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-drawable, robolectric

I am trying to retrieve a `bitmap` and save to my local disk on PC.
As a result I get a jpeg file (95 bytes) which cannot be read.

source:

```
Application application = new MyApplication();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(application.getResources(), drawableId);

File outputFile = new File("D:\\OutputFile.jpg");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
IoUtils.closeSilently(os); //close stream
```

P.S. I know that I can't get `bitmap` from `drawable`. But I don't know why...